# Add margin left to \section and \subsection

Tags: sectioning, formatting, sections-paragraphs

I am looking for a way to change the margin form the left of the titles in LaTeX. I´ve added a picture to clarify my concern:

[image: How it should look like]

Is there a way, to change the margins of the titles of the sections, and only the titles, and not the entire paragraph below?

Comment: Could you please add information on which document class you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For standard classes (not KOMA script classes as leandriis has pointed out)
you can use the [titlesec package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) to change the format and spacing of sections, subsections and so on. See page 4 for an explanation of `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing` and their optional arguments which I have not shown here for simplicity.

I have changed the `<left>` argument of the `\titlespacing` command to an arbitry value of `1em` (which is usually 0). Change it however you want.
The other values in the code below are taken from subsection 9.2. Standard Classes on page 23 and should be the values usually used by LaTeX.

The example below indents sections. Indenting subsections and subsubsections works in the same way.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

%\titleformat
%   {\section} % <command>
%   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries} % <format>
%   {\thesection} % <label>
%   {1em} % <sep>
%   {} % <before-code>

\titlespacing* % starred version: first paragraph is not indented
    {\section} % <command>
    {1em} % <left>
    {3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex} % <before-sep>
    {2.3ex plus .2ex} % <after-sep>


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \section{Test}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add the document class you have used to test your solution? For me it works fine with standard classes, however due to the incompatibility with the `titlesec` package, it does not work with `KOMA script` classes. Information on how to indent sectioning heading using `KOMA script`classes can be found for example here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227936/134144

Comment: @leandriis thanks for the hint. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Lebyproc I am glad if I could help. If the answer has answered your question please accept it.